# Set background image to cover according to viewport size

Tags: html, css

With respect to the mentioned subject, I would like to know how to add code that will set the background image size to cover the window completely without the sides getting cut off.
I have tried using height and width auto,cover and 100% but none are working.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you need your background image to be distorted to get 100% width and height?

Comment: No, no distortion. Just the image!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html{ width:100%; height:100%; 
      background:#fff url(image.jpg) center center no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Comment: This is still cutting off the edges!

Answer (score 9):

Use the CSS `background-size` property.

If you want your background image to fill the area to the minimum width/height use:

`background-size: cover;`

If you want your background image to fill the area as large as possible but still show all your image use:

`background-size: contain;`

Comment: The bottom of the image is still getting cut off :(

Comment: then use the contain property, that will make sure that as much of the image is being shown without being cut off

Comment: Use `background-size: contain` rather than `background-image: contain`.  Answer edited.

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm suspect it's because I'm using viewport... maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found it! I used a div to wrap the whole content inside the body with the ID 'wrapper' and then used the following CSS code:

```
#wrapper
{
background-image: url('Media/bg.jpg');
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
left:0;
}
```

Thanks for all the help! :)